# Displaying a string, from an array within an array with JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I currently use *iReport 5.1.0*, *Tomcat 7*, *Java*, *Spring MVC* amongs other things.
I believe my current problem lies within the *iReport* itself, although it may be more complex.

I currently have an *Object* (*Guide*),
My *Guide* has a list of *Objects*, (*itemsGuide*)
My *itemsGuide* has a list of *Objects*, (*itemsTeam*)
My *itemsTeam* has a list of *Objects*, (*professional*)
My *professional* has a *name*.

My *jasper* file, receives as parameter the *Guide*, in the *iReport* software I must assign the fields and the current variables, although I must print, in a single line, parameters from the *itemsTeam* object (a couple of strings), and in this very specific case I will always have only one *professional*, although the variable lies within a list, therefore I must access the first object in this array to then display its attribute.

I keep getting the most unusual errors as I try to do this rather simple process.
The *iReport* either doesn't find the variables in *itemsTeam* or the ones in *professional*, when, for some unknown reason it "works" my preview of the PDF (it says "The document has no pages", to avoid the error msg I change the attribute in my report proprety, but now, it simple shows the *iReport* file without any field/variable, only the graphical elements).

I am utterly confused, would anyone be so kind as to lend a hand to this poor newcomer?

the JRXML file has over 37k characters and I can't post it as an edit, I uploaded as a txt file insted.
Thanks in advance.

No more need for the link to the xml ~

-- CATURDAY EDIT --
Allright, I seem to be getting closer to my solution.
At this point I've tried quite a few different approaches to my problem.
Although I couldn't completely solve it, I managed to get closer, or so I believe.
Now, all I have to find out (it seems) is:
How to access an array within an array.
I managed my way around the guide and the itemsGuide, I can't access the array within itemsGuide, I need to access a variable named "team" within that array (itemsGuide) and then print the value of a few strings in this array (which is of a specific class, itemsTeam) and a string in an object (professional).
All this, without subreport.
Anyone ?

Allright, what I spent about 4 days trying to find out, my co-worker with more experience than me found out in about 20 minutes.
The issue wasn't within iReports itself, it was necessary to create methods in the class in order to return the desired object/list, something I did not even consider given that I know very little of how iReports (and java honestly) works.
But according to what I understood from what has been done it has something to do with reflection and a couple of methods in the java class.

Thanks guys. :>

Comment: You should post your code and *jrxml* file

Comment: I'll try *again* to use the subreport functionality, although such thing does not meet my current requirements.

Comment: Nope, no can do, I'm not allowed to change the current scope of the projects display, I'll have to find a way around my first solution.
I'm out for today but I'll come tomorrow and I'll find a solution to share.

Comment: your ireport file(the JRXML file) would make this much easier for us to help you you.  you may be able to use the list or table component if a sub report is out of the question.

Comment: No success at all.
Things are proving to be rather complex.
If anyone is able to shed a light, please, do so.